# How to create an iOS LaunchScreen.storyboard for a flutter app?

Tags: ios, storyboard, flutter, screen, launch

I am preparing to release an iOS app created with flutter and need to create a launch screen.  Creating different sized assets for each screen size seems like a pain, and the recommended approach for iOS development is to use a storyboard that looks like the first screen of the app.  Is there anyway to do this with flutter without trying to create my own storyboard in Xcode?  Otherwise I would have to try to create a storyboard that resembles what I created in flutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To add an image to the center of your “splash screen”, navigate to
>   `.../ios/Runner`. In, `Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset`, drop in
>   images named `LaunchImage.png`, `LaunchImage@2x.png`, `LaunchImage@3x.png`.
>   If you use different filenames, you’ll also have to update the
>   Contents.json file in the same directory.
>
> You can also fully customize your launch screen storyboard in Xcode by
>   opening `.../ios/Runner.xcworkspace`. Navigate to `Runner/Runner` in the
>   Project Navigator and drop in images by opening `Assets.xcassets` or do
>   any customization using the Interface Builder in
>   `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.

Checkout: https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#updating-the-launch-screen